# Coderay rendering weird symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using [Coderay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/) 1.1.0 in my Rails 4.1.4 project for rendering syntax-highlighted code block.

The original code looks like this:

```
Book = Struct.new(:title, :episodes)
book = Book.new("Harry Potter", 7)

book
# => #<struct Book title="Harry Potter", episodes=7>

book.title
# => "Harry Potter"
book[:title]
# => "Harry Potter"
book["title"]
# => "Harry Potter"
```

I use

```
CodeRay.scan(code, :ruby).html(:css => :class)
```

But the result looks like this:

```
Book = Struct.new(:title, :episodes)
book = Book.new("Harry Potter", 7)

book
# =&gt; #&lt;struct Book title="Harry Potter", episodes=7&gt;

book.title
# =&gt; "Harry Potter"
book[:title]
# =&gt; "Harry Potter"
book["title"]
# =&gt; "Harry Potter"
```

A lot of weird symbols just show up. Can't figure out what to do. Any suggestion on solving the problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html_safe` renders the html content correctly on the view, but it does not remove the weird strings in my case. However, it turns out that Coderay adds some stuff into my code, so that the `html_safe` method does not successfully escape the symbols. I don't know where it comes from but you can see the `amp;` substring in the following code:

```
code.gsub!("&amp;quot;", "&quot;") 
code.gsub!('&amp;#39;' , "&#39;" ) 
code.gsub!('&amp;gt;'  , "&gt;"  )
```

As a result, I remove the `amp;` substring in every punctuations and symbols I want to insert, and the `html_safe` method will successfully render the content.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the output as `html_safe`, then Rails will not escape the special characters:

```
CodeRay.scan(code, :ruby).html(:css => :class).html_safe
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still the same. There are still there. I also tried in my rails console but something like `CodeRay.scan("#=> hello",:ruby).html.html_safe` will produce `"<span class=\"comment\">#=&gt; hello</span>"` String, in which the `&gt;` is not escaped.